# norm of linear operator less than or equal to abs of eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

$A: V\longrightarrow V$ linear operator
V finite dimensional inner product space

(1) Show that $|b|$ is less than or equal to $||A||$ where b is any eigenvalue of $L$.

(2) Now let $L$ be self-adjoint. Show

$||L|| = \max\{|b|\}$

---

My attempt:

(1) - I think this is close to a solution

$Ax = bx$

$||Ax||^2 = (Ax|Ax) = (bx|bx) = |b|^2 (x|x)$

so

$||A|| = |b| sqrt((x|x))$

If i can show $\sqrt{(x|x)}$ is $0$ or greater than I'm done but I don't know how to do so.

(2) - just an idea probably not the correct way to go

$(Ax|Ax) = (x|AAx) = |b|^2 (x|x)$

idk i can't figure out how to even start part (2). i can't think of how $||A||$ has to be max of $|b|$

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that $|b|\leq ||A||$. Take any  eigenvalue $b$ and a corresponding eigenvector $x$ of unit norm.$||A||\geq|Ax|=|bx|=|b|$.

Now, if $A$ is self adjoint, there exists an orthonormal eigenbasis $\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$. Any vector, $x=\sum c_i e_i$  and $Ax=\sum b_ic_ie_i$.

If $x$ is of unit norm, then $\sum c_i^2=1$ $|Ax|^2=\sum c_i^2b_i^2\leq b_{max}^2$. So, $||A||\leq b_{max}$.

Using the previous part, $||A||=b_{max}$

Comment: how did you get ||A|| greater than |Ax| and how did you deduce |bx| = |b|?

Comment: $x$ is eigenvector with norm 1, $\|x\|=1$, then $\|bx\| = |b|$.